# Linq - merging sub lists from different objects into a single object

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object which has a date and a list of people, a person has a first and last name. Something like:

```
PeopleInfo
----------
DateTime - StartDate
List<Person> - People

Person
------
string - FirstName
string - LastName
```

I have a list of people info where there are multiple `StartDates` the same each with its own list of people. Is it possible to merge these into a single object using linq?

### Example

```
StartDate - 1/1/2011, People Bob, Sue, Jane
StartDate - 2/2/2011, People Scott, Rob, Mark
StartDate - 1/1/2011, People Fred, Gill, Jack
```

### Expected output

```
StartDate - 1/1/2011, People Bob, Sue, Jane, Fred, Gill, Jack
StartDate - 2/2/2011, People Scott, Rob, Mark
```

Is this possible in linq?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do:

```
List<PeopleInfo> peopleInfos = ...

var merged = from peopleInfo in peopleInfos
             group peopleInfo by peopleInfo.StartDate into dateGroup
             select new PeopleInfo
             {
                 StartDate = dateGroup.Key,
                 People = dateGroup.SelectMany(pi => pi.People)
                                   .Distinct()
                                   .ToList()
             };
```

But this really looks like a hack; I would recommend you design the container class in a way that prevents this 'duplicate date' scenario from occurring in the first place. e.g. an implementation of `ILookup<DateTime, Person>` or `IDictionary<DateTime, List<Person>>` or a `HashSet<PeopleInfo>` that uses `StartDate` for equality.

Comment: Thanks that works great. A better implementation is a good idea but what I'm doing is just a hack for the time being anyway.

Comment: I would agree the OP model leaves something to be desired, but your solution is spot on!

Answer (score 1):

```
ILookup<DateTime, Person> lookup =
  (
    from pi in PeopleInfos
    from person in pi.People
    select new {StartDate = pi.StartDate, Person = person }
  ).ToLookup(x => x.StartDate, x => x.Person);
```

OR

```
List<PeopleInfo> list =
  (
    from pi in PeopleInfos
    from person in pi.People
    group person by pi.StartDate into g
    select new PeopleInfo() { StartDate = g.Key, People = g.ToList() }
  ).ToList()
```

Comment: +1. I would warn that while this is correct, it unnecessarily flattens the whole input collection and does the grouping from scratch.

Comment: Unnecessary flattening?  What does it cost?